# USB communication between Arduino Mega ADK 2560 and Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: arduino, galaxy

I try to provide a usb communication between Arduino Mega ADK 2560 (there are two types of it, I use the one having two usb ports on it) and Samsung Galaxy S2 whose version 2.3.5 (custom build). However, when I try demokit code given in Arduino's website, I always get an error which is `error 5 : Device descriptor cannot be retrieved. Trying again.`

Demokit code includes;

```
AndroidAccessory acc("Google, Inc.",
             "DemoKit",
             "DemoKit Arduino Board",
             "1.0",
             "http://www.android.com",
             "0000000012345678");

acc.powerOn();
acc.isConnected();  ---error occurs here!
```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be an error at that line, but `acc.powerOn()` should definitely throw an error; this function is private. Use `begin()`, not `powerOn()`. One references the other anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Although ADK was backported to Android 2.3.4, many vendors did not include the necessary kernel modifications with the firmware. I myself struggled from the same problem fo a very long time. I tried different 2.3.5 custom and official ROMS but I could not find a working kernel available.

The problem is no more with the ICS. The official ICS releases include kernels with proper ADK support.